# How to do i use wamp server to host godaddy domain

Tags: http, wamp, web-hosting

So i have bought a domain from godaddy
I have installed wamp got it running so if i put my local ip it goes to my website
i have port forwarded my ip
Now how do i use my domain to access my website hosted in wamp

I have done this also today. How do I host my own website with my purchased domain name from my own laptop?
Edit: I can confirm that if i type my ip in it works good on any wifi or data

Answer (score 0):

To use the domain purchased now you need a DNS server. So that I link your domain name with the IP of your apache server.

If you have a fixed IP. See if you can assign this IP from the Godady panel.

If you have a dynamic IP, you must use a third-party service that may be able to link the dynamic IP and update it for your domain name.
There are many services, but I recommend: https://dyn.com/dns/ or https://freedns.afraid.org/

Comment: thank you. I have found another way to by pass that by just assigning the ip for a value in the panel but still thank you i will try to do this also

Comment: i can not assign the ip for some reason, i first made two hosts then assigned that in the name servers it wont work and i have a static ip too